# Shibboleth SAML2 LogoutRequest needs to include NameID

Tags: logout, shibboleth, gigya

I am trying to set up SLO with a Shibboleth SP and a Gigya IDP. The IDP has SLO set up and all the redirections appear to be working, however the IDP is expecting a saml:NameID tag to be present within the LogoutRequest, and Shibboleth is not doing this by default.

Here is the request that Shibboleth is currently generating:

`<samlp:LogoutRequest
    Destination="............"
    ID="_863ce41c221f009f853ebe1fbad30548" IssueInstant="2016-09-01T01:14:44Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">..........</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Extensions><aslo:Asynchronous xmlns:aslo="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol:ext:async-slo"/></samlp:Extensions>
    <saml:EncryptedID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
            xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
                            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
                    </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                    <xenc:CipherData>...</xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>...</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </saml:EncryptedID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>`

I would like to have the below tag included within the samlp:LogoutRequest tag.

`<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">.......</saml:NameID>`

I know a nameid is being generated because I see the tag present in the login response saml.
Can the SLO request be configured to include this value?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that the NameID Element is encrypted, which might be causing your problem. Did you try disabling Encryption?

Comment: You are 100% correct! I set the encryption attribute on the Logout tag to false and I am now seeing the nameID attribute appear in the LogoutRequest tag. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Mehmet Y. pointed out, the nameID attribute was in fact already being included, though it was encrypted. I had to explicitly set the encryption attribute on the Logout tag to false in order to get the IDP to recognize it.